# How to add an oblique bar to a button

Tags: css, html

So this is what I did so far :

```css
#mybutton {
    background-color: #08c2f3;
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 6px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align :center;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

body {
    background-color: #1599e1
}

#myBar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 9px;
    background: white;
    transform: rotateZ(-54deg);
    position: relative;
    left: 42px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mybutton">
  <span>OK</span>
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

but my goal is :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `overflow: hidden` to the parent container as it will hide your unwanted portion peeping out.

```css
#mybutton {
  background-color: #08c2f3;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 6px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: #1599e1
}

#myBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 9px;
  background: white;
  transform: rotateZ(-54deg);
  position: relative;
  left: 42px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mybutton">
  <span>OK</span>
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need the "bar" element at all.

This can be achieved with an angled background gradient

```css
#mybutton {
  background: linear-gradient(124deg, #08c2f3 70%, white 70%, white 75%, #08c2f3 75%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 6px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

body {
  background-color: #1599e1
}
```

```html
<div id="mybutton">
  <span>OK</span>
</div>
```